# Background 100% height, left

Tags: html, css, background

I tried to position a BG image that it has 100% height and auto width while it is left-justified. No success so far.
Is it possible anyhow?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see you tried anything.

Comment: what is 100% height, 100% of image or of page? same question for auto for width, what do you mean? and also what is left justification of image? did you mean left-aligned ? is this what you were trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/FgGhe/

Comment: excuse me; I am dyslexic. I mean that the BG has 100% height of the page and is RIGHT-aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand the question, but would `background-image: [image url]` be an answer to your problem?
What @Banana suggested would work pretty much the same too.

Answer (score 0):

I would use CSS for this by giving it an ID let's say `id="bg"`

```
#bg {
    background-image:url('bg.png');
    height:100%
    float: right;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean '#bg' and not just 'bg'